# Swift 3 Realm accessed from incorrect thread on main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm

I'm calling the Realm on the main thread using the DispatchQueue.main.async and it throws an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 
'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'
```

Here's the code:

```
func add(word: String, toList list: WordList, completion: @escaping ((_ success: Bool) -> (Void))) {

    let listId = list.timestamp

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {

        guard let json = TranslationManager.shared.translateFrom(list.from, to: list.to, text: word, autocorrect: true) else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(false)
            }

            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let newWord = Word()
            newWord.text = word
            newWord.timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
            newWord.json = json.rawString(String.Encoding.utf8, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) ?? "{}"
            newWord.translated = json[NativeJsonIndexes.translated].stringValue

            let realm = try! Realm()
            let currentRealmList = realm.objects(WordList.self).filter({
                record in
                return listId == record.timestamp
            }).first

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(newWord)
                currentRealmList?.words.append(newWord)
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I don't get why it could possibly work incorrectly, as all the Realm interaction is happening in the main thread and the only external object is passed using ThreadSafeReference class

Comment: On which line is the error prompted?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti xcode doesn't show it, it shows the error on the "}" of DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: I think the problem is related to the ThreadSafeReference. ThreadSafe only assure that the variable is not accessed from different threads at the same time: it doesn't assure that there's only 1 thread at all. Try commenting the lines in which you use that Reference and let me know

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I tried just passing an Int id and retrieving the object inside DispatchQueue.main.async block and the error stays

Comment: @AndriiLiakh if you did it right, passing an id and retrieving the object should have definitely worked, could you please share your code of that attempt? Also, if you set up an exception breakpoint in debugger, you should be able to see exactly which line is causing the issue.

Comment: @AndriiLiakh then your error is elsewhere, for example in `completion(false)` method

Comment: @DávidPásztor I updated the code, it doesn't work this way too

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the `completion(false)` isn't called and it even doesn't have any Realm interaction

Comment: The problem is, you are still using the list itself as an input argument to your function. You should try using list.timestamp as an input argument and not a WordList object itself. Btw why are you trying to do your Realm interactions asynchronously on the main thread? Unless you are writing thousands of objects, I don't see any point in doing this asynchronously or even doing it explicitly on the main thread. Calling the completion handler on the main thread makes no sense to me either.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I use background thread because `translateFrom()` makes a synchronous web request. Completion is called on the main thread as it contains UI interaction.

Comment: How would a completion handler containing a single bool do any UI interaction? My question was about why you do a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` inside your execution block on the background thread... Since you declare your realm instance in a local scope, you can safely do that on the same background thread as the `translateFrom` call.